# Finding russian document of PCT-application

Tags: pct, russia, eapo

Assume I have the number of a PCT application ([example](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2011128254A1?cl=nl)).

How do I find the russian document? In the linked example it does say, however google doesn't link the russian version and entering the WO number into the [russian patent search field](https://www.eapo.org/en/ru.html) doesn't yield any result.

To summarise, I need the published russian-national-phase document of any given PCT application.

> 13. Nov. 2012  ENP Entry into the national phase in:
>
> Ref document number: 2012147905
>
> Country of ref document: RU
>
> Kind code of ref document: A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case right choise would be to use Espacenet, as in my experience the coverage is the largest among the free patent databases. Simply use 
WOYYYYYYYYYY, where yyyyyyyy is the number of the application, in your example WO2011128254.

https://worldwide.espacenet.com/?locale=en_EP

Comment: Oh, apparently I tried searching for a non-published russian app. and therefore thought espacenet didn't have russian documents. You're right, with that example espacenet does have it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The document Russian  publication of WO2012147905 you are specifically looking for is [here](http://www1.fips.ru/wps/portal/IPS_En#1516406406393). This [link is to a Russian information retrieval system](http://www1.fips.ru/wps/portal/IPS_En#1516406355137). However, the PCT application WO2011128254 in your example link does not appear to have ever entered the national stage in Russia,

Answer (score 0):

Official publication of RU2012147905 is [here](http://www.fips.ru/Archive/PAT/2014FULL/2014.05.20/DOC/RUNWA/000/002/012/147/905/DOCUMENT.PDF), and its prosecution data may be seen [here](http://www1.fips.ru/fips_servl/fips_servlet?DB=RUPAT&DocNumber=2012147905&TypeFile=html).
The application was rendered withdrawn on 11.01.2016.

Data of any RU application may be found in the [Registers](http://www1.fips.ru/wps/portal/Registers/).

P.S. Do not mix up RUPTO (Rospatent) with EAPO (Eurasian Patent Office); they are different patent organizations, and they have separate patent registers.